# Sending a php value to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, parameters

I currently have the following code -

```
echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick=personchange(".$row['first_name'].")>".$row['first_name']."</button>";
```

What I am trying to do is: Display all the first names I read from the database as buttons and once the user selects one of these names, it then calls a javascript function and I want to pass the first name the user selected as a parameter to this function. Right now when I have this code no buttons and the first names are not even shown.

Can someone please tell me if what I am doing is wrong and how I can do it better.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may miss quotes around function call, and function agruments of `personchange`. Try this:

```
echo "<button type='button' class='btn btn-link' onclick='personchange(\"".$row['first_name']."\")'>".$row['first_name']."</button>";
```

They are needed, when string argument is passed.

Also I suggest to:

1. check if function `personchange` defined in your javascript.
2. escape `$row['first_name']` with [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) or something like it: for the cases when `$row['first_name']` has value with quotes.

---

I also recommend to use another output style:

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-link\" onclick=\"personchange('{$row['first_name']}')\">{$row['first_name']}</button>";
```

It might be more obvious.